# query with Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I make this query in Laravel, using Eloquent ORM?

```
select * from posts p order by ( select count(*) from likes where flag = 'c' and p.id = post_id ) Desc limit 3
```

I have this relationship in my models

Post.php

```
public function likes(){
    return $this->hasMany('Like', 'post_id');
}
```

Like.php

```
public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Post', 'post_id');
}
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: select count(*) from likes where flag = 'c' and p.id = post_id 
-- will return number. 
Do you really need something like  select * from posts p order by ( 9999 ) Desc limit 3
You need a coulmn or expression

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
$posts = Post::leftJoin('likes', function($join) {
        $join->on('posts.id', '=', 'likes.post_id')->where('flag', '=', 'c');
    })
    ->select('posts.*', 'likes.post_id', DB::raw('count(likes.post_id) as pCount'))
    ->groupBy('post_id')
    ->orderBy('pCount', 'desc')
    ->take(3)
    ->get();
```

Comment: You'd rather **not** select `likes.*` here (probably redundant, for sure overriding `posts.id` in the result) and `leftJoin` would be more accurate.

Comment: You are right, updated it thanks @JarekTkaczyk, I must admit that, you've eagle eyes :-)

Comment: I got this error: 
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "likes.post_id" does not exist LINE 1: ...posts".*, "likes"."post_id", count("likes.... ^ (SQL: select "posts".*, "likes"."post_id", count("likes.post_id") as pCount from "posts" left join "likes" on "posts"."id" = "likes"."post_id" and "flag" = c group by "post_id" order by "pCount" desc limit 3).

But i have this column likes.post_id in my DB

Comment: Make sure your `likes` table has `post_id` field as `foreign key` of `posts` table, it should work.

Comment: It has :(

CREATE TABLE likes
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  post_id integer NOT NULL,
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  flag character(1) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT likes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT likes_post_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (post_id)
      REFERENCES posts (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT likes_user_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

Comment: Don't use `"` in the count.

Comment: Thanks again, it's a habitual problem @JarekTkaczyk :-)

Comment: Now the error is:
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "pCount" does not exist LINE 1: ...and "flag" = $1 group by "post_id" order by "pCount" d... ^ (SQL: select "posts".*, "likes"."post_id", count(likes.post_id) as pCount from "posts" left join "likes" on "posts"."id" = "likes"."post_id" and "flag" = c group by "post_id" order by "pCount" desc limit 3)